# In creating a calculator keypad, I used grid divs and used a onclick toDisplay function to display the value on the interface. How do I get the data

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, grid

How do I get the data from the div keypad in order to use for any functions within my javascript file?

What other methods are there to use?